# Searching for elements in an array with spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string, spaces

I created a building directory and it basically shows the user the entire directory (using a string array) and if they don't want to view the entire directory they can just search for the specific business in the building. However, I cannot seem to get the search option to work because in my array there are spaces in-between.. eg:

String Floor [] = { "Ground Floor", "Vacant" };

If I remove the space in-between "Ground Floor" and make it "GroundFloor" it can then be searched, otherwise it just comes up as not found if you search "Ground Floor". What can I do to fix this?

bones of program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Townsendtest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

//prints the Floor Number of index and he Business listed on the floor
System.out.println("Floor Number\t\tBusiness"); 

//String array of businesses on each floor starting at floor 0-24
String floor [] = { "Ground Floor", "Advanced Technologies", "HiMark Marketing", "Law offices 
of John Daniels", "PST Systems", "Century United Brokers Inc.", "Creative Resources", "Design 
Centre Associates", "Ideal Media Group", "SF Net Developers", "Shears medical Services Inc.", 
"Green Space Construction Inc.", "Cornerstone Mortgage Capital", "Allied Advantage Realty", "JAMS 
the Resolution Experts", "Law Offices of Matt Dill", "Vacant", "The Drop in Centre", "Artisan 
Interiors Consultancy", "NGS Group", "Robert  H. Greene Real Estate", "Vacant", "Vacant", "Denise 
A. Patterson Attorney at Law", "Conference Rooms 1-6" };

//for loop to print entire index to the user
for(int counter=0; counter<floor.length; counter++ ){  
System.out.println(counter + "\t\t\t" + floor[counter]);

}//end for loop


Scanner businessname = new Scanner(System.in);
String namefind;

System.out.print("Enter the name of the Business: "); 
namefind = businessname.next();

for(int i = 0; i < floor.length; i++){

if(namefind.equalsIgnoreCase(floor[i])) {
System.out.println("Business Found!");
System.exit(0);
}
}
System.out.println("Business not found, try again");


}//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: This sounds more like a logical error in your search method. You may want to post that method for us to help solve your issue.

Comment: We can't tell you where the bug is in your code and how to improve it without seeing the code.

Comment: Possibly also an issue how the input is collected and/or propagated to the search routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a scanner, its basic next method will give you the next token, i.e., something delimited by white space.

Use nextLine to get a complete line containing user input, trim leading and trailing spaces and use this in the search.

```
namefind = businessname.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
namefind = businessname.next();
```

Use

```
namefind = businessname.nextLine();
```

So that it takes space into account as well.

Comment: Not really a solution to OP's problem.

Comment: I guessed that in my comment even before that. Thanks for repeating my answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **BufferedReader** instead of **Scanner** for your requirement. it's more efficient way.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();
```